# Java AffineTransform moving origin

Tags: java, graphics, affinetransform

I would like to move the origin from top left to bottom middle of the component?
I have been playing with AffineTransform class could not get it to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need the height and width of the component that you are trying to draw.  Assuming you are in the `paint(Graphics g)` method the simplest way is:

```
paint(Graphics g){

Graphics2D g2 =  (Graphics2D)g;

g2.translate( component.getWidth()/2.0, component.getHeight()/2.0);

//...

}
```

Comment: this has moved the origin but everything is still upside down.